# SWP 6.0 TeX compilation error

Tags: pdftex, pdf, scientific-workplace

I had a working version of Scientific Workplace 6 (SWP 6) on my old laptop.  I just got a new laptop and I installed SWP 6 on it.  The version was downloadable for free from a legit site. I then added my old license number to the newly installed software.
Everything seems to work fine, except the PDF compiler. When I click on "PDF preview", the compilation fails.  I get a "TeX Error" stating "Unable to Create a PDF file".
I am not sure what is going on, it did not happen on my old laptop.
Did this happen to anyone?
Thanks,
Zsolt

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Is there an support for that software available? Have you asked them?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you can find swp a commercial product Downloadable for free. Besides MacKichan who made swp went out of business in June. Btw doesn't swp also require a separate latex installation as well?

Comment: I would not use 6.0. Better to use 5.5 if you can still download it for free.